# Dynamics AX 2012 Financial Dimensions

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

How can I get similar results to my ax09 query,

```
SELECT DIMENSION, DIMENSION2_ FROM CUSTTABLE
```

in Dynamics AX 2012?

I understand the tremendous complexity of the new dynamic dimension structure. With this new structure is there even a way to reproduce a select statement like the one above?

Here are the tools I have to work with:

```
1. SQL Server Management Studio 2008
2. DAX AOT
3. BIDS (MS SQL Server 2008 R2 (SSRS))
```

Comment: I see that you have added an ssrs tag, and therefore assume you want a T-SQL example, and not one using X++ helper classes?

Answer (score 4):

There is a great article here about creating a helper class to solve this exact problem;

http://learnax.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/dynamics-ax-2012-financial-dimensions.html

This is the new code Nagaraj Jadhav has posted on his blog to achieve this;

```
static void DEV_Dimension(Args _args)
{
    CustTable                         custTable = CustTable::find("1101");
    DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage dimStorage;
    Counter i;

    dimStorage = DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage::find(custTable.DefaultDimension);

    for (i=1 ; i<= dimStorage.elements() ; i++)
    {
        info(strFmt("%1 = %2", DimensionAttribute::find(dimStorage.getAttributeByIndex(i)).Name,        
                               dimStorage.getDisplayValueByIndex(i))); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look in the white paper [Implementing the Account and Financial Dimensions Framework](http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh272858) for a description of how Default dimensions are implemented. There is a view DefaultDimensionView that you can use to retrieve dimension information:

```
SELECT DEFAULTDIMENSIONVIEW.NAME, DEFAULTDIMENSIONVIEW.DISPLAYVALUE, CUSTTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM
FROM DEFAULTDIMENSIONVIEW 
INNER JOIN CUSTTABLE 
ON DEFAULTDIMENSIONVIEW.DEFAULTDIMENSION = CUSTTABLE.DEFAULTDIMENSION
```